# Compare attributes of objects, change element class/tooltip if different

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

With the following code:

```
public class Person {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private List<Dog> dogs;
}

public class Dog {
    private Long id;
    private Long oldId;
    private Long age;
}
```

I have 2 objects of Person, 'person' and 'editedPerson'. I want to compare the two, and if one attribute is different, change the class of a element and create a tooltip showing the value of the other object's attribute. And I want to be able to do this inside a ng-repeat too, compare Dog attributes inside persons list based on their id/oldId (compare the dog inside the ng-repeat with the dog that has the same oldID as dog's id)

This is an example of how I've been doing so far:

```
<b ng-class="{ 'different' : person.name != editedPerson.name)}"
tooltip="{{(person.name != editedPerson.name) ? 'New: ' + editedPerson.name : ''}}">
Name:</b>
<p>{{person.name}}</p>
```

The problem is that I'll have a LOT of attributes, and some of them are inside Lists of different types. The sollution I have for the List so far is to create one function for each attribute, for example

```
compareDogAge = function(dog, dogs) {
    // Foreach on dogs until dogs[i].oldId == dog.id, return true if age is equal
}
```

I would like to know if I should keep my current solutions, or try to make/find a directive that can solve my problem (I have very little experience on making directives).

Thanks in advance

***EDIT***

I came up with the following function so far, but haven't tested it yet

```
equals = function(fieldName, originalObj, newObj) {
    if (newObj instanceof Array) {
        for (var i = 0; i < newObj.length; i++) {
            if (originalObj.id == newObj[i].oldId) {
                return originalObj[fieldName] == newObj[i][fieldName];
            }
        }
    } else if (newObj instanceof Object){
        return originalObj[fieldName] == newObj[fieldName];
    }
}
```

I still think a directive would be better

Answer (score 1):

Angular has a **equals** function, isn't that what you a looking for?

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.equals

```
angular.equals(person, editedPerson);
```

**Edit**

A directive do add this logic to you component would look like this:

Html

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="myDir">
        <span different old-value='foo' new-value='bar'>FooBar</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Angular

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []).directive('different', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){

            //Add your logic to check the differences here
            //You can use the function you already have
            if (attrs.oldValue !== attrs.newValue){

                //Do other stuff you want to do with the element here
                element.addClass('different');                
            }

        }
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/marcosspn/8ucakhk5/

Comment: I just saw that you want to know what attribute that is different. In this case my answer won't help.